# How to add key and Value if the array key does not exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a dictionary in JavaScript by checking for the objects property.

```
   var item = {};
   if(item.hasOwnProperty("xyz")){
       //do wat is required
   }else{
       //add the key property to the item object
   }
```

How to add this "xyz" key property to the object is my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `item.xyz='Whatever'` and `xyz` will be added to `item`

```
var item = {};
if (item.hasOwnProperty('xyz')) {
    console.log('item has xyz');
} else {
    item.xyz = 'something';
    //item["xyz"] = 'something'; You can also use this
}
console.log(item);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu33/)

Comment: what if `item.xyz` equals to `0` or `false` or `null`, in these cases `item.xyz` exists, but it will be treated like when that is not exists

Answer (score 1):

Just do `item.xyz` and assign whatever you want to that.

```
item.xyz = 'abc';
```

Then you can just check for `item.xyz`

Answer (score 1):

if you need to assign that, there is no need to any check:

```
item["xyz"] = "something";
```

if `xyz` exists on item, it will be assigned else it will be created

Answer (score 0):

```
  var item = {};
   if(item.hasOwnProperty("xyz")) {
       alert('Item has already that property');
   } else {
      item.xyz= value;
   }
```

Comment: what if `item.xyz` equals to `0` or `false` or `null`, in these cases `item.xyz` exists, but it will be treated like when that is not exists

Comment: you are right. I have corrected my answer. thanks for suggestion.